# C#: Remove the spacing at the edges inside a button

Tags: c#, string, button

Situation: I need a tiny button, with some text on it.

Problem: The button seems to think displaying empty space near its edges is more important than displaying my Text.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to remove that blank stuff at the edges. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

-MonsterMaw

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET or winForms button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about WinForms, you can set the `FlatStyle` property of the button to `System`.

That will let you resize the button so that it is small enough for the text to fit exacty, without any internal padding.

Comment: What if I need it to have FlatStyle = Flat? (I need to set border color)

Answer (score 1):

You could override the OnPaint method on the button and then draw it however you like. I think you could use the base.OnPaint to draw the button without any text and then draw the text on yourself with pevent.Graphics.DrawString?

Answer (score 1):

Consider whether this is desirable, though.  Users expect some sort of standard behaviour from our applications, so if you're trying to bend the rules to make it non-standard, you should at least consider the fact it might not be the correct solution.

Other options include moving your UI commands to menus/toolbars and links, if buttons aren't doing it for you.

Answer (score 1):

A LinkLabel is a good choice for this (assuming it fits your overall UI).  It's *just* text, so you don't have to worry about borders or padding at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the Text property of your Button to empty. Then place a label over the top of the button, if all else fails...

Edit. Don't forget to set your label's backcolor to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

It's very old topic but maybe somebody will find it useful.

See my proposition below. I create custom Button control and I override `Text` property to be able to use its private part `_Text` and attach `String.Empty` just before `MyBase.OnPaint(e)` event. This makes that button is draw without text. Later on I reassign old text to the private property and draw string myself. I add `Inflate` to `Rectangle` to make text nicer just touching border of button, not overlapping it. My proposition works with any `flatstyle` attribute.

[Here comparison of standard button and no padding button in two flatstyles: standard and flat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKZGC.png)

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class ButtonNoPadding
    Inherits Button

    Private _textCurrent As String
    Private _Text As String

    <Category("Appearance")>
    Public Overrides Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return _Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If value <> _Text Then
                _Text = value
                Invalidate()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)

        _textCurrent = Text
        _Text = String.Empty
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        _Text = _textCurrent

        Using brush = New SolidBrush(ForeColor)
            Using stringFormat = New StringFormat() With {.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center}
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, Rectangle.Inflate(ClientRectangle, -2, -2), stringFormat)
            End Using
        End Using

    End Sub

End Class
```

C# version:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class ButtonNoPadding : Button
{

    private string _textCurrent;

    private string _Text;
    [Category("Appearance")]
    public override string Text {
        get { return _Text; }
        set {
            if (value != _Text) {
                _Text = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        _textCurrent = Text;
        _Text = string.Empty;
        base.OnPaint(e);
        _Text = _textCurrent;

        using (brush == new SolidBrush(ForeColor)) {
            using (stringFormat == new StringFormat {Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center}) {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, Rectangle.Inflate(ClientRectangle, -2, -2), stringFormat);
            }
        }

    }

}
```